# Splitting TensorFlow Dataset created with make_csv_dataset into 3 parts (X1_Train, X2_Train and Y_Train) for multi-input model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am training a deep learning model with Tensorflow 2 and Keras. I read my big CSV file with `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` and then split it into train and test datasets. However, I need to split my train dataset into three parts since my deep learning model takes two set of inputs in different layers so I need to pass `[x1_train, x2_train],y_train` to `model.fit`.

My question is that how can I split `train_dataset` into `x1_train,x2_train` and `y_train`? (some features shall be in `x1_train` and some features shall be in `x2_train`).

My code:

```
def get_dataset(file_path, **kwargs):
  dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
      file_path,
      batch_size=64, 
      label_name=LABEL_COLUMN,
      na_value="?",
      num_epochs=1,
      ignore_errors=True, 
      **kwargs)
  return dataset

full_dataset = get_dataset(dataset_path)
full_dataset = full_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=400000)
train_dataset = full_dataset.take(360000)
test_dataset = full_dataset.skip(360000)
test_dataset = test_dataset.take(40000)
x1_train =train_dataset[:,0:2820]
x2_train =train_dataset[:,2820:2822]
y_train=train_dataset[:,2822]
x1_test =x_test[:,0:2820]
x2_test =x_test[:,2820:2822]
y_test=test_dataset[:,2822]
model.fit([x1_train,x2_train],y_train,validation_data=[x1_test,x2_test],y_test, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=1,epochs=EPC)
```

Error message:

```
x1_train =train_dataset[:,0:2820]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'TakeDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: After constructing your dataset, and before doing anything else, use `map` method of `tf.data.Dataset` object to split each batch.

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can use map to split each batch?

Comment: The first element of each batch returned by `make_csv_dataset` is a dictionary mapping column names to their values. So in the map function you can split this dictionary into two separate dicts (and possibly combine the items in each dictionary into a separate tensor for each according to your model's input format).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments sections, you can use `map` method `Dataset` object which is returned by `make_csv_dataset` in order to split and combine the samples according to your model's expected input format.

For example, suppose we have a CSV file containing the following data:

```
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,111
5,6,7,8,222
9,10,11,12,333
13,14,15,16,444
```

Now, suppose we want to read this CSV file with `maks_csv_dataset` function; however, our model has two input layers named `input1` and `input2` (set using `name` argument of `Input` layer) where `input1` is fed the feature values in column `a` and `b`, and the `input2` uses the feature values in column `c` and `d`. Further, the column `e` is our target (i.e. label) column.

So let's first read this data and see how it looks like:

```
from pprint import pprint

dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
      'data.csv',
      batch_size=2,
      label_name='e',
      num_epochs=1,
)

for x in dataset:
    pprint(x)

"""
The printed result:

(OrderedDict([('a',
               <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([5, 1], dtype=int32)>),
              ('b',
               <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([6, 2], dtype=int32)>),
              ('c',
               <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([7, 3], dtype=int32)>),
              ('d',
               <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([8, 4], dtype=int32)>)]),
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([222, 111], dtype=int32)>)
(OrderedDict([('a',
               <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([13,  9], dtype=int32)>),
              ('b',
               <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([14, 10], dtype=int32)>),
              ('c',
               <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([15, 11], dtype=int32)>),
              ('d',
               <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([16, 12], dtype=int32)>)]),
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([444, 333], dtype=int32)>)
"""
```

As you can see, the first element of each batch is a dictionary mapping column names to the respective feature values. Now, let's use `map` method to split and combine these feature values into proper format for our model:

```
first_input_cols = ['a', 'b']
second_input_cols = ['c', 'd']

def split_and_combine_batch_samples(samples, targets):
    inp1 = []
    for k in first_input_cols:
        inp1.append(samples[k])
    inp2 = []
    for k in second_input_cols:
        inp2.append(samples[k])
    
    inp1 = tf.stack(inp1, axis=-1)
    inp2 = tf.stack(inp2, axis=-1)
    return {'input1': inp1, 'input2': inp2}, targets

dataset = dataset.map(split_and_combine_batch_samples)

for x in dataset:
    pprint(x)

"""
The printed values:

({'input1': <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 9, 10],
       [13, 14]], dtype=int32)>,
  'input2': <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[11, 12],
       [15, 16]], dtype=int32)>},
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([333, 444], dtype=int32)>)
({'input1': <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[5, 6],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int32)>,
  'input2': <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[7, 8],
       [3, 4]], dtype=int32)>},
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([222, 111], dtype=int32)>)

"""
```

That's it! Now you can further modify this new modified dataset (e.g. use `take`, `shuffle`, etc.) and when ready you can give it to `fit` method of your model (don't forget to give names to input layers of your model, though).

Comment: Thanks. I applied your code and added some extra lines:
`dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=400000)`
`train_dataset = dataset.take(360000)`
`test_dataset = test_dataset.take(40000)`
`model.fit(train_dataset,validation_data=test_dataset, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=1,epochs=4)`

where my model has 'input1' and 'input2' as input layer names. However, now training is stuck in Epoch 1/4 and I get no error. What is the problem?

Comment: @hsn15051 How large are the data and your model?

Comment: Dataset: 412k samples. I have 2822 features totally. I am training a fully connected neural network. I pass 2820 features into some layers and then concatenate result with 2 more features and give to some other layers and finally get output (I use https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional). I am trying to optimize architecture so I need to train/validate thousands models on GPUs (I am using MirroredStrategy. ). Soon, I will have 500k features so I will need to scale up

Comment: @hsn15051 Doesn't the training show any progress/error at all if you wait longer? How many parameters are in the model? Use `model.summary()` or `model.count_params()` to find out. Can you monitor GPU utilization to see if it's being used at all when training starts?

Comment: I do not get any error. Model has 350k parameters. I have 4 GPUs (each 100% GPU-Util and almost 95% RAM usage when I monitor with `watch -n0.5 nvidia-smi`). I use 25% of CPUs and 25% RAM when I monitor with `top` command

Comment: I doubled GPU and CPU. Now, GPU usage is around 2% and something is being run and I see this:
`96/Unknown - 76s 795ms/step - mse: 5190.4185 - loss: 5190.4185`
Why do I have /Unknown in this line?? (96 is a number and it increases so there is no end to this epoch!!!)

Comment: @hsn15051 That refers to the number of training steps, i.e. batches. It's unknown probably because it cannot be inferred automatically. It's weird that it shows a high utilization, but doesn't progress. Can you also check the shape of samples generated by the dataset? Take one sample from dataset and check their shape.

Comment: There is definitely something fishy going on since I get very high error (Previously, it got small error). I can share my code (send to your email if that helps)

Comment: This is shape of dataset.take(1) `<TakeDataset shapes: ({input1: (None, 2820), input2: (None, 2)}, (None,)), types: ({input1: tf.int32, input2: tf.float32}, tf.float32)>` Sounds good to me

Comment: @hsn15051 If it's possible for you, share it as a Google Colab notebook. It's strange that the batch size in `None`, it should have been inferred automatically. One more thing to try: reduce your model to the minimum size possible (e.g. use only one layer with one unit) and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219608/discussion-between-today-and-hsn15051).

Comment: @today - I'm getting an error:    `split_and_combine_batch_samples  *
        inp1.append(samples[k])

    TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str` Any ideas?

Comment: @scribbles It's strange that you get such an error because it implies that the `samples` is a tuple instead of a dictionary; however, the `make_csv_dataset` constructs the input samples as feature dictionaries, not tuples (as I have shown in the answer). Anyways, to check the format, print one of the samples in the constructed dataset and then adjust the solution in my answer accordingly. That's all I can say without seeing your code/data.

Comment: @today. Thanks! Switching from `from_tensor_slices` to `make_csv_dataset` did the trick. Would have thought they'd output equivalent objects but maybe not.