# How to make train_test_split on a dataset created with make_csv_dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

For a small dataset, I was using scikit-learn `test_train_split` on a dataframe of the whole dataset as

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train, test = train_test_split(features_dataframe, test_size=0.2)
train, test = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2)
```

And it simply create a test, train, validation split on my dataset.
Now, I want to perform data-loading from the disk i.e., my csv files. So, I'm using the experimental tf.data function [`make_csv_dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset). What I have done is

```
import tensorflow as tf

defaults=[float()]*len(selected_columns)

data_set=tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    file_pattern = "./processed/*/*/*.csv",
    column_names=all_columns,   # array with all columns labels
    select_columns=selected_columns, # array with desired column labels
    column_defaults=defaults,      # default column values
    label_name="Target",
    batch_size=10, 
    num_epochs=1,
    num_parallel_reads=20,
    shuffle_buffer_size=10000,
    ignore_errors=True)
```

As far as I guess is, I have the dataset, but when I try to perform `train_test_split` of scikit-learn, it don't work and the reason is obvious, the data_set is not loaded yet, its just configured to be loaded.

How, to perform train, test, validation split on this data?

I have gone through some guides, and everyone (as far as I come across), is loading the training data:

[overfit_and_underfit](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit)

[custom_training_walkthrough](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough)

[estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/estimator)

Comment: But I don't have a dataframe now, it's dataset

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63345725/14290681) help you?

Comment: @TFer2 check my answer to see what worked for me so far

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to have a better control overmy dataset, I used a lower level similar API i.e., [CsvDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset). Then I manually spitted dataset in two different folders for test and train splits and loaded separately as

```
import pathlib

training_csvs =  sorted(str(p) for p in pathlib.Path('./../Datasets/path-to-dataset/Train').glob("*/*.csv"))
testing_csvs =  sorted(str(p) for p in pathlib.Path('./../Datasets//path-to-dataset/Test').glob("*/*.csv"))

training_dataset=tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(
    training_csvs,
    record_defaults=defaults, 
    compression_type=None, 
    buffer_size=None,
    header=True, 
    field_delim=',',
    use_quote_delim=True,
    na_value="",
    select_cols=selected_indices
)
print(type(training_dataset))

testing_dataset=tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(
    testing_csvs,
    record_defaults=defaults, 
    compression_type=None, 
    buffer_size=None,
    header=True, 
    field_delim=',',
    use_quote_delim=True,
    na_value="",
    select_cols=selected_indices
)

print(training_dataset.element_spec)
print(testing_dataset.element_spec)


training_dataset= training_dataset.shuffle(50000)
validate_ds = training_dataset.batch(300).take(100)
train_ds = training_dataset.batch(300, drop_remainder=True).skip(100)

test_ds = testing_dataset.batch(300, drop_remainder=True)
```

Now, it's working but one problem is left and that is, validation dataset. Ideally, validation dataset should be different for each epoch, but in this case it's same so, training for multiple epochs is not improving performance. If anybody can help to resolve this issue, I would be grateful.